# Do we need a keyword for "gridding"

Tags: discussion

In oil exploration I sure hear the word "gridding" used a lot.  It seems to be used more loosely than the definition offered [here](http://www.glossary.oilfield.slb.com/Display.cfm?Term=gridding).

Given the googleability of this term (and the budgets of the people who use it), should we have a tag for gridding?

If so, what definition should we use?  Should it be specific to geology?

Comment: gridding can be used - if defined correctly.

Comment: For a company that [does so much gridding](http://www.halliburton.com/halcomsearch.aspx?k=gridding), it sure seem like Halliburton would define what it means.

Answer (score 1):

We currently have [grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) and [grids](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grids).  Did you have something else in mind?

Tags generally develop organically and naturally when a new question or reply suggest a need.  What we might do at this point is monitor the uses of the grid-related tags and take care to clarify conceptually different uses if they arise.  If you think it's worthwhile, we can also create tag synonyms, such as [gridding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gridding) as a synonym of one (or both) of the existing tags.